# How do I write this code without refactoring?

Tags: java, refactoring

I recently got help writing a statement checking if input text was blank or only whitespace. I got it working but do not really understand the code since its too advanced refactoring for me. Could someone please translate this to more basic code?

```java
name = name == null ? "" : name.trim();
```

Comment: if(name == null) { name =""; } else { name = name.trim(); }

Comment: how more basic do you want it to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is similar to:

```
String name = //your input
if(name==null)  {//if name si null
    name = "";//assign empty string
} else {
    name = name.trim(); //remove leading and trailing whitespace
}
```

The if else is replace with "? :" operator

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are seeing is a "ternary operator". It follows this syntax:

```
boolean ? ifTrue : ifFalse
```

Ternary operators do not work quite like if/else statements: They provide you with a value (like `3 + 4`).

So in this example, you set `name` to the result of the following ternary expression:

```
is name null? -+- true --> ""
               |
               +- false -> name.trim() (this function removes whitespace at
                                        the beginning and at the end of the string)
```

You could also write:

```
public static String parseName(String name)
{
    if (name == null)
        return "";
    //else (else not neccesary here)
        return name.trim();
}

// in some block...
name = parseName(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

if `name` is equal to `null` it will be equal to "";

else it will be equal to `name.trim()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 name = name == null ? "" : name.trim();
```

that means

```
 String name;
 //You performed some processing here, your logic.
 if(name==null){
  name="";
 }
 else{
  name=name.trim();
 }
```